# Get record of mongo from list array mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, atomic

I use mongo, and I have a little problem here. I want to get a record, but I just have the id of an array list inside record. This is what my data looks like.

```
{    
   "_id": ObjectId("1113000001"),    
   "menu": "desertsunday",   
  "fruit": {
      "0": ObjectId("102b000000"),
      "1": ObjectId("5200000000"),
      "2": ObjectId("2900000000"),
      "3": ObjectId("9870000002")   } 
 }
```

I just have 102b000000 for get the record, I need to get the menu from there but I can't get it with standard mongo. Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually fruit in you schema is not array, it is list of objects, because of this there is only one  way to get root document by one fruit id:

```
db.items.find({"fruit.0": ObjectId("102b000000")})
```

In above query you should know ordinal number of fruit to fetch root document.

But if you can redesign your database as follows:

```
{    
   "_id": ObjectId("1113000001"),    
   "menu": "desertsunday",   
   "fruit": [
      { i:0, id: ObjectId("102b000000") },
      { i:1, id: ObjectId("5200000000") }
    ]
}
```

you can easy fetch root doc by embedded array item id:

```
db.items.find({"fruit.id": ObjectId("102b000000")})
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree with most of what Andrew says, but instead, I would re-design the schema so that you actually have an array. In that case your document would look like:

```
    {    
       "_id": ObjectId("1113000001"),    
       "menu": "desertsunday",   
       "fruit": [
          ObjectId("102b000000"),
          ObjectId("5200000000")
        ]
    }
```

Then you can fetch the root document with:

```
    db.items.find({"fruit": ObjectId("102b000000")})
```

Comment: yea, if he don't really need ordinal number of fruit, then array of ids will be better option.